# Converting boolean to integer

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I was wondering why

```
recommendation=false;
var val = "Bipin " + recommendation?1:0;
console.log(val);
```

returns

```
1
```

but

```
recommendation=false;
var x=recommendation?1:0;
var val = "Bipin " + x;
console.log(val);
```

prints

```
Bipin 0
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: You could consider being cool and use `+!!recommendation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"Bipin " + recommendation?1:0;
```

is interpreted as

```
("Bipin " + recommendation)?1:0
```

in which case

```
"Bipin " + recommendation(is always truthfully)
```

hense the result is always 1

like @Qantas 94 Heavy pointed out this is an operator precedence issue you need to do

```
 "Bipin " + (recommendation?1:0);
```